# Passing View object as parameter in a Write method

Tags: android

I have the following code sample that performs a write to file in Android:

```
public void Write(View v) {
    String contents = txt1.getText().toString();
    try {
       FileOutputStream f = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(f);
       w.println(contents);
       w.close();
       f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();     
    }
}
```

my question is, what does the View object (passed as parameter) do, and why is it necessary? I understand that a view refers simply to a UI object in Android but I am unable to find any explanation on what the View object does here.

Comment: Does it mean there is a code `onClick` attribute in one of your `Views` in `XML` may be a button??

Comment: yes, there is a button that is assigned this method as a handler

Comment: I have answered your question! @czolbe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now know that android just implements the `onClickListener` for you when you define the `android:onClick="yourMethod"` attribute to your Views.

It is not necessary for it to be a `Button` you can put to any view even `TextView` remember all this are subclasses of `View`.

So for Android to implement `onClickListener` for you. You have to pass a `View` as a parameter.

For your question's `Write` method you were not interested on the `Button` that was clicked so the `View` was not used. But take an example for someone who wants to change a `Button's` text when the user clicks, so the `View` parameter must be casted to a `Button` and then used. Check this example below for a `Button` with an attribute:

```
android:onClick="changeText"
```

The method `changeText` will be called and the `View` parameter is a view that was passed for this case the `Button` so the method will be:

```
public void changeText(View view) {
    Button btn =(Button) view; //See how I have retrieved the Button by simply casting!
    btn.setText("I am clicked");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped me. To test my understanding, the view here refers to the ui object acting as the source of the event (onclick), which triggers the write method. And by having a reference to the button, or view that triggers the write method, we have the option to